# Script not running in loaded template of Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, templates, google-chrome-extension

Sorry for the long post. I'm pretty new to Chrome Extension development. I'm trying to inject a sidebar that gets visible when I click my floating element. Template is loading fine but any sort of script that I've already loaded from my contentscript isn't getting respected in my template. For example, I'm trying to template things using Mustache.js which is getting Mustache as undefined. Here's my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "The Explorer", "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "An extension for chrome", "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
    },
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>" ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [ "app/html/*", "vendor/*" ]
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId) {
    var scripts = ["vendor/jquery-3.1.0.min.js", "vendor/mustache.min.js", "script.js"],
    injectScripts = function(scriptArr) {
        if (Array.isArray(scriptArr)) {
            var script = scriptArr.splice(0, 1)[0];
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: script},
                injectScripts.bind(null, scriptArr));
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: scriptArr});
        }
    };
    injectScripts(scripts);
});
```

script.js:

```
(function() {
    var myIcon;

    (function createmyIcon() {
        myIcon = document.querySelector('.my-shortcut-icon');

        if (!myIcon) {
            myIcon = document.createElement('div');
        }
        myIcon.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar);
        document.body.appendChild(myIcon);
    })();

    var sidebarOpen = false;

    function toggleSidebar() {
        var sidebar = document.getElementById('my-sidebar');

        if (sidebarOpen) {
            sidebarOpen = false;
            myIcon.style.right = '0px';
            sidebar.style.width = '0px';
        } else {
            if (!sidebar) {
                sidebar = document.createElement('div');
                sidebar.id = "my-sidebar";

                document.body.appendChild(sidebar);

//Loads my template here
                $("#my-sidebar").load(chrome.extension.getURL('app/html/test.html'));
            }

            sidebarOpen = true;
            myIcon.style.right = '300px';
            sidebar.style.width = '300px';
        }
    }
})();
```

And here's my template (test.html):

```
<div id="target">Loading...</div>

<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    Hello {{ name }}!
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Mustache.parse($('#template').html());
    $('#target').html(Mustache.render($('#template').html(), {
        name: "Luke"
    }));
</script>
```

Any idea on where I am making the error?

Comment: Debug the injected scripts by using console.log or debugger; statement. And don't use simple id for elements, they WILL eventually conflict with some page. Use a more complex and long id or switch to classes.

Comment: Clearly Mustache (or any other scripts - a script with assigning a value in window object) hasn't loaded in my template which I've stated above @wOxxOm

Comment: Yes, it has got injected, I can get reference of Mustache from my script.js. But my loaded template isn't getting it. Funny enough, its getting jQuery

Comment: My script.js itself is an injected script which is using chrome.extension.getUrl() here to load the template file here. I can see the text "Loading..." from my template. But its not doing anything as Mustache isn't getting in as defined there

Comment: Well, I would simply move that code into script.js without wasting my time. Maybe someone else will explain what actually happened.

Comment: Maybe jQuery is too smart and its `.load` method evaluates the `<script>` elements in some kind of eval sandbox. Anyway, dividing code between the injected script and an html template seems a very bad idea. Usually the template is accessed directly in the `load`'s callback.